# Regarding Bit Fields in Structure and Union

Tags: c++, struct, bit-manipulation, unions

When using bit fields inside structures like:

```
struct abc{
  int a:3;
  unsigned int b:1;
} t;
```

So, my question is, do variables (with set bit-fields) **share the same memory space** even inside **structures**? Because when I saw their representation it looked like - first, `a` will have 3 bits(from LSB) then 1 bit for `b` (MSB) and all in one 4-byte(32 bits) memory space.

In case of **Unions**:

```
typedef union abc {
  unsigned int a:32;
  int f:1;
} t;

int main()
{   t q;
    q.a = (unsigned int)(pow(2,32)-1);
    q.f = 1;
    cout << sizeof(t) << endl;
    cout << q.a << " " << q.f << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

First of all, the sizeof() operator returns *4 bytes as the maximum size for this union*
and as **32 bits** are set for variable 1 then **how** can it even manage **space for variable b**?

Thank you for reading till the end, I'll really appreciate your answers.

Comment: looks like c++?

Comment: In a union `f` overlaps a bit of `a`. In a struct `a` and `b` are disjunct, 4 bits. That haphazardly the number of bytes remain the same in a struct is due to the small number of bits.

Comment: Just for us to see _where exactly_ you are stumbling: Do you know the difference between `struct` and `union`? I ask this because I don't understand "_[...] how can it even manage space for variable b_" for the union.